# Python: Matplotlib Install Issues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have mac OSX 10.7.5 and I'm trying to install matplotlib, but I keep having issues.

```
Kristas-MacBook-Pro:lib Krista$ brew install matplotlib
==> Installing matplotlib dependency: numpy
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.8.1/nump
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/numpy-1.8.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nose/nose-1.3.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/numpy--nose-1.3.1.tar.gz
==> python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.8.1 --single-vers
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-python/issues
```

I'm not sure what to do? I tried brew doctor etc, as suggested by that website, but am just lost. Any help?

---

When trying to install distribute I get this error (and when trying to upgrade setuptools, I also get it)

```
Kristas-MacBook-Pro:lib Krista$ pip install distribute
Downloading/unpacking distribute
  Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB): 145kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/1z/b3f7sbv11gv2jvy113vy8m180000gn/T/pip_build_Krista/distribute/setup.py) egg_info for package distribute

Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute)
  Downloading setuptools-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (528kB): 528kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: setuptools, distribute
  Found existing installation: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r85381
    Uninstalling setuptools:
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 293, in move
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/easy_install.py'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Krista/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `setuptools` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or install `Distribute` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3)

Comment: I got an error when trying to do both of those. It's the same error for both things. I've added it to the bottom of my question because it's too long for a comment

Comment: @user132039 You need to be root user for that. Do `sudo pip install distribute`

Comment: What does it mean to be root user? Also, it didn't work. It said it couldn't find the file.

Comment: I tried it, but it still didn't work. *edit* I did get the installation of distribute to work. However, now I'm getting the issue (when I try to install matplotlib):                         * The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype

But I know for a fact that I have it because if I try  brew install freetype, it tells me I already have it.